# Woocommerce add order notes to failed order admin email

Tags: php, woocommerce

I need to add a specific order note in woocommerce to a failed order email to the admin.

I am using the following code in functions.php which works - except it places all comments in the email.

I only want notes with the text "Error processing payment blah blah blah" in them to be added to the email such as this example:

Error processing payment. Reason: Processor Declined – Possible Stolen Card

Below is the code I am using - how do I make it filter and add only those notes which contain the text "Error processing payment" in them and not send all comments?

```
// Add comments to Failed order emails

add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woo_add_order_notes_to_email', 10, 3 );
function woo_add_order_notes_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin = true, $plain_text = 
false ) {

// You want to send those only to the Admin
if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {
    return;
}

// You can also check which email you are sending, by checking the order status
// Optional, comment it out, if not needed
if ( 'failed' != $order->get_status() ) {
    // Will end execution, with everything other than the completed order email.
    return;
}

$notes = array();

$args = array(
    'post_id' => $order->id,
    'approve' => 'approve',
    'type' => '' // You don't need type as orders get only order notes as comments.
);

// Remove the filter excluding the comments from queries
remove_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ) );

// You get all notes for the order /public and private/
$notes = get_comments( $args );

// Add the filter again.
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments', 'exclude_order_comments' ) );

echo '<h4 style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:120%;line-height:110%;color:red;">IMPORTANT Order Notes</h4>';
echo '<ul class="order_notes">';
if ( $notes ) {
    foreach( $notes as $note ) {
        $note_classes = get_comment_meta( $note->comment_ID, 'is_customer_note', true ) ? array( 'customer-note', 'note' ) : array( 'note' );
        ?>
        <li rel="<?php echo absint($note->comment_ID); ?>" class="<?php echo implode(' ', $note_classes); ?>">
            <div class="note_content">
                <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( $note->comment_content ) ) ); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo '<li class="no-order-comment">There are no order notes</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
}
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [**`wc_get_order_notes`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-order-functions.html#source-view.1003) function to get all notes *based on a specific order id*.

You will need to create an array to use as a function parameter with the following keys:

- `limit` as an empty field (no limit)
- `order_id` the order id of which to get notes

Finally you can use the PHP [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function to check that the count contains the string *"Error processing payment"*.

```
// Add comments to Failed order emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'woo_add_order_notes_to_email', 10, 4 );
function woo_add_order_notes_to_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {

    // You want to send those only to the Admin
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {
        return;
    }

    // You can also check which email you are sending, by checking the order status
    // Optional, comment it out, if not needed
    if ( 'failed' != $order->get_status() ) {
        // Will end execution, with everything other than the completed order email.
        return;
    }

    // Get the admin order notes
    $args = array(
        'limit'    => '',
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
    );
    $notes = wc_get_order_notes( $args );

    // If there are no notes
    if ( empty($notes) ) {
        echo '<li class="no-order-comment">There are no order notes</li>';
        return;
    }

    echo '<h4 style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:120%;line-height:110%;color:red;">IMPORTANT Order Notes</h4>';
    echo '<ul class="order_notes">';
    foreach( $notes as $note ) {
        // Print only the note containing the string "Error processing payment"
        if ( strpos( $note->content, 'Error processing payment' ) !== false ) {
            $note_classes = $note->customer_note ? array( 'customer-note', 'note' ) : array( 'note' );
            ?>
            <li rel="<?php echo absint($note->id); ?>" class="<?php echo implode(' ', $note_classes); ?>">
                <div class="note_content">
                    <?php echo wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( $note->content ) ) ); ?>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: This works for when an order fails on a WooCommerce Subscriptions RENEWAL order, but for some reason, no error notes appear in the email when it is a NEW WooCommerce Subscriptions order that fails. (But when I look in the admin dashboard, there are order notes on the failed NEW order). I get the IMPORTANT Order Notes header in the email but no notes.